# Tor broswer won't connect

Tags: connection

I used to be able to connect just fine till 2 weeks ago and it started to do this for no reason. I haven't change anything on my computer to cause this. Is tor network down or something?

```
5/16/19, 14:52:50.907 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:52:50.907 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:52:50.907 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:52:50.908 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:52:50.908 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:52:50.908 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
5/16/19, 14:52:50.908 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\Rainboom\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.2" 
5/16/19, 14:52:51.450 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
5/16/19, 14:53:47.904 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host F2044413DAC2E02E3D6BCF4735A19BCA1DE97281 at 131.188.40.189:443) 
5/16/19, 14:53:47.904 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
5/16/19, 14:53:47.904 [WARN]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
5/16/19, 14:53:47.904 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:53:47.924 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:53:47.924 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:55:05.839 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:55:05.839 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "bridges" (was using "default") 
5/16/19, 14:55:05.839 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:55:05.840 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:55:05.840 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:55:05.840 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:55:06.777 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges 
5/16/19, 14:55:07.377 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host 0872E07DE33BEE2EB5D6A9941EBF30885A5D80D7 at 199.231.94.203:443) 
5/16/19, 14:55:07.377 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
5/16/19, 14:55:07.377 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
5/16/19, 14:55:07.377 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:55:07.389 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:55:07.389 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:55:14.627 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:55:14.627 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:55:14.627 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:55:14.627 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:55:14.627 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:55:16.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host 0872E07DE33BEE2EB5D6A9941EBF30885A5D80D7 at 199.231.94.203:443) 
5/16/19, 14:55:16.200 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
5/16/19, 14:55:16.200 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
5/16/19, 14:55:16.200 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:55:16.210 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:55:16.210 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:55:25.667 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:55:25.667 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:55:25.667 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:55:25.667 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:55:25.667 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:55:47.616 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 13; recommendation warn; host F9D5819CBA9432635243E1B78BF5FDC5EB13EBE3 at 137.194.11.147:34897) 
5/16/19, 14:55:47.616 [WARN] 13 connections have failed: 
5/16/19, 14:55:47.616 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
5/16/19, 14:55:47.616 [WARN]  2 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:55:47.627 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:55:47.627 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:56:05.275 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:56:05.275 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:56:05.275 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:56:05.275 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:56:05.275 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.376 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host 0DB8799466902192B6C7576D58D4F7F714EC87C1 at 216.252.162.21:46089) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.376 [WARN] 15 connections have failed: 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.376 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.376 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.397 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.397 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.397 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 15; recommendation warn; host CDF2E852BF539B82BD10E27E9115A31734E378C2 at 192.95.36.142:443) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.397 [WARN] 17 connections have failed: 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.397 [WARN]  13 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.397 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.397 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.398 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 16; recommendation warn; host 0BAC39417268B96B9F514E7F63FA6FBA1A788955 at 38.229.33.83:80) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.398 [WARN] 20 connections have failed: 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.398 [WARN]  14 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.398 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.398 [WARN]  3 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.399 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 17; recommendation warn; host C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 at 38.229.1.78:80) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.399 [WARN] 22 connections have failed: 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.399 [WARN]  15 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.399 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.399 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 18; recommendation warn; host FB70B257C162BF1038CA669D568D76F5B7F0BABB at 144.217.20.138:80) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.400 [WARN] 26 connections have failed: 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.400 [WARN]  16 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.400 [WARN]  7 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:56:12.400 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:57:04.587 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:57:04.587 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:57:04.587 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/16/19, 14:57:04.587 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:57:04.588 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:57:26.541 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 19; recommendation warn; host F9D5819CBA9432635243E1B78BF5FDC5EB13EBE3 at 137.194.11.147:34897) 
5/16/19, 14:57:26.541 [WARN] 32 connections have failed: 
5/16/19, 14:57:26.541 [WARN]  16 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
5/16/19, 14:57:26.541 [WARN]  13 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:57:26.541 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/16/19, 14:57:26.556 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/16/19, 14:57:26.556 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
```

Comment: THIS HAPPENED TO ME WHEN I MOVED THE TOR FOLDER like i dont know why the flying fu## doesnt the Torproject warn you of this

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your internet provider is blocking your access to Tor. You can use a bridge to try to connect. This link will give you more information on how to use bridges. https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en